# Is there any way to stop exposing Lightning Controller logic in browser console?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

Actually, I wrote all the business logic in the lightning controller and helper class, Because of that it is exposing all the business logic and data in browser console when I click on "inspect element" option. How do I stop exposing controller code and data in browser console? Is there any way or any feature of lightning which can do this?

Answer (score 2):

As of today code hiding or code obfuscation is not possible in lightning components but its one of those things which may be done in the future for lightning components.Nothing concrete though.

Check this our [minify source code](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/173269/plans-for-obfuscation-of-lightning-component-source-when-delivered-in-a-managed)